# Tesseract use of number-dawg

Tags: dictionary, pattern-matching, tesseract

I need to specify a numeric pattern. I already made training normally.

I created a config file that has the line

```
    user_patterns_suffix user-patterns
```

and the file user-patterns contains my patterns, for example:

```
    :\d\d\d\d\d\d\d.
    :\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d;
    !\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d}
```

then I launch tesseract with the config file over a tif, and it tells me "Error: failed to insert pattern " message, for the first two patterns. It ultimately acts as if no pattern has been issued.

I need to recognize only and ever that patterns, and tried to train a language with a number-dawg file, but then, when using tesseract command, I got a segmentation fault.

I used in the number-dawg file its conversion of the above patterns:

```
    :       .
    :         ;
    !        }
```

The questions, as the google documentation is not clear, and I do not speak english:

1. the patterns file, where have to be used? I suppose number-dawg has to be used during training, but I got seg fault so couldn't try with it, and user-patterns during recognition phase, when launching Tesseract, but didn't work. Where am I doing errors?
2. do I need a dictionary, also, when training with number-dawg? I have a digit and punctiation only set of possible characters, and all the possible numbers in the digits, a dictionary is not possible. If I need to use dictionaries, how could I do?

Thanks in advance for help, any hint would be very appreciated

Comment: Is the file named `eng.user-patterns`? See [documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html).

Comment: No, it is named mylang.user-patterns, as I am using custom language. Do I need other dawgs besides user-patterns when tesseracting an image for OCRing?